# Laravel auth AJAX no popup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Ive been going through this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785)

Everything works fine from a terminal cURL request but I get a popup for authentication when using jQuery. Is there a way to prevent this popup and pass the login credentials from jQuery to the API? How exactly does --user work from terminal and how do I "simulate" this from jQuery?

Terminal:

```
$ curl --user username:password http://localhost/api/v1/email
{"error":false,"authEmail":"me@localhost","message":"request success"}
```

Laravel controller method:

```
public function index() {
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'authEmail' => Auth::user()->email,
        'message' => 'request success'), 200);
}
```

Laravel filter:

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function() {
return Auth::basic('username');
});
```

Laravel route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function() {
Route::resource('email', 'EmailController');
});
```

jQuery:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/v1/email',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        }
    }).complete(function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON);
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the beforeSend callback to add the authentication information:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        ajax({

            url: 'http://localhost/api/v1/email',

            type: 'GET',

            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader(

                "Authorization",     

                "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password')); }

            })

            .complete(function(data) {console.log(data.responseJSON)})

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Cool this works perfectly. So is this how you would have to do it for other APIs aswell? Just a matter of setting headers? I assume the same applies to PHP then?

Comment: The headers need to be set when using basic authentication. Normal authentication uses POST data or whatever you have set it to use, but HTTP Basic Authentication is part of the HTTP standard and requires the correct headers.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a username and a password setting to your jQuery ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/v1/email',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    }).complete(function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON);
});
```

I think that should work.

Comment: That seems to be working as im getting a valid JSON response now but im also seeing a console error: "NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://username:password@localhost/api/v1/email". Any idea what this error is about considering the authentication is working?